# My rstudio just stopped working and its giving me this notice window ''Error Starting R''

Tags: r, rstudio

[image]

I tried uninstalling and installing it again but it kept on bringing up that error window, I even went on to download a newly released version but the problem kept coming up without any success of opening r. It cannot open any working window.

Comment: Can you open R outside of RStudio?

Comment: did you recently update rstudio? if so try the previous version you were using